# NPE in JavaFX Task

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I implemented this code example in order to load data from database:

```
...........
    Tab tabdata = new Tab();
                            Task<VBox> task = createLoadImagesTask(data);
                            StackPane stack = createVeiledPane(task, 120, 120);
                            runTask(task);
                            tabdata.setContent(stack);
                            AgentsDataStage.addNewTab(tabdata, newValue.getValue().toString());
    ............


private static Task<VBox> createLoadImagesTask(final InternalData data)
    {
        return new Task<VBox>()
        {
            @Override
            protected VBox call() throws Exception
            {

                    TabContent contentc = new TabContent();
                    return contentc.initTestTabContentData();

            }
        };
    }

    private static void runTask(Task<? extends Node> task)
    {
        Thread taskThread = new Thread(task, "Task Runner");
        taskThread.setDaemon(true);
        taskThread.start();
    }

    private static StackPane createVeiledPane(Task<? extends Node> task, double prefWidth, double prefHeight)
    {
        Region veil = new Region();
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
        veil.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
        ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
        double progressSize = Math.min(prefWidth, prefHeight);
        clampSize(progress, progressSize * 0.75);
        progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().setAll(veil, progress);

        task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t)
            {
                stack.getChildren().setAll(task.getValue());
            }
        });

        return stack;
    }

    private static void clampSize(Control control, double size)
    {
        control.setMinSize(ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE, ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        control.setPrefSize(size, size);
        control.setMaxSize(ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE, ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    }
```

When I run the code and I click several times on the TreeView node where I start the code I get this stack exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.findMatchingStyles(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.createStyleHelper(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.reapplyCss(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$19(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin$IndeterminateSpinner.rebuild(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin$IndeterminateSpinner.access$400(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin$2.invalidated(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.css.StyleableIntegerProperty.set(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty.setValue(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.css.StyleableIntegerProperty.applyStyle(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.css.StyleableIntegerProperty.applyStyle(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$31(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$401(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$146(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can you advice what is causing this exception?
Can this be related to threads?

**Update:**

Same result with this code:

```
public void addNewTab(DynamicTreeNodeModel nodeModel)
    {
        final Tab tab = new Tab();

        final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        final Task<BorderPane> loadDataTask = new Task<BorderPane>()
        {
            @Override
            public BorderPane call() throws Exception
            {
                Content content = new Content(primaryStage, treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                return content.initContentData();
            }
        };
        tab.setContent(progressBar);
        loadDataTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event)
            {
                BorderPane data = loadDataTask.getValue();
                tab.setContent(data);
            }
        });
        final Thread thread = new Thread(loadDataTask);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        newTabLabel = new Label(nodeModel.getName());
        tab.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent;");  // Remove the blue dashed label from label
        tab.setGraphic(newTabLabel);
        tab.setContextMenu(makeTabContextMenu(tab, newTabLabel, tabPane));

        tabPane.getTabs().add(0, tab);  
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);  
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS);  
    }
```

Comment: Are you using fxml somewhere in your program or defining css styles to some component in your code? This error seams to be related to applying a CSS style. The nullpointer is probably because the Loader didn't find any match for the CSS style set to the component. Please, post an example that can be reproduced anywhere.  Check this link, please : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No I don't use fxml.

Comment: Are you applying a CSS style at any other place in your code?

Comment: Please, edit your question and include the css file and the code where your're using the css file and its classes. Probably the error is at this point.

Comment: I removed all css code and css files but still I get the same error.

Comment: What is AgentsDataStage, InternalData and TabContent? What is newValue? Do you understand that the code you gave is not enough to reproduce the execution? please, create a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you to solve this issue.

Comment: I created a brand new project and removed the AgentsDataStage, InternalData and TabContent from your code. I've got no Exceptions.

Comment: It turns out that this is a JavaFX bug https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40417. It will be fixed in 8u60.

Comment: FYI, the early access release for 8u60 is available now: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html